# How to disable the table header sorting for a data table

Tags: 2013, datatable

I am using the following code to generate a datatable...

```
var dataTable =  $('#projectDashboard').DataTable( {
                    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "bDestroy" : true,
                    "tableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "http://sharepoint.company.com/sites/test/Resources/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "sRowSelect": "multi",
                        "aButtons": []
                                        }
                } );
```

And the table is generated perfectly fine, but I need to disable the table header sorting. How can I do that?

Comment: While Datatables is a bit offtopic as it's not directly related to SharePoint i think that this one will be closed sadly.

Comment: But we do use it in sharepoint....Any solution will be appreciated

Comment: But before it get's delete, try to add "bSort" : false, as a property in your DT

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
var dataTable =  $('#projectDashboard').DataTable( {
                    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                   " bSort": false
                    "bDestroy" : true,
                    "tableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "http://sharepoint.company.com/sites/test/Resources/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "sRowSelect": "multi",
                        "aButtons": []
                                        }
                } );
```

Hope it will works for you.